# Conditions needed to apply Green's theorem and "homotopic" argument

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, greens-theorem

I was asked the following question:

Given the following vector fields
$$
G(x,y)=(-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}),$
$$
$$
H(x,y)=a G(x,y-1) + bG(x,y+1),
$$
and the path defined by
$$
r=\{\ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: ^2 + (\frac{y}{4})^2=1   \wedge y\ge0 \},
$$
calculate the work done on the path from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ along $r$ by the vector field $H$.

On the previous exercises, it was already proven that $H(x,y)$ is closed and the work done on the line that goes from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ is given by $\frac{\pi (a-b)}{2}$

At first I thought that I could apply Green's theorem, since the vector field is closed I would get $0$ and then I would just need to subtract the work done on the line. But for some reason, when I checked my resolution with my teacher's, the results obtained were different.

The way he solved involved using some kind a"homotopic" argument, which I didn't understand where he calculated the work done on a circunference radius 1 around $(0,1), (cos(\theta),1+sin(\theta))$.

I presumed that I couldn't use Green's Theorem but why? And secondly what is this "homotopic" argument and how to use it to solve this kind o problems.

Comment: If someone could edit this question it would be appreciated :)